# File content in Javascript in a Browser

Tags: file, xmlhttprequest

The only way I know to take the contents of a local file and push those bytes to a server is to set up a form post with an `<input>` of appropriate type to prompt the user to select a file.

I would like to do the same thing only pushing the data through `XMLHttpRequest` (no cross-scripting tricks).

Currently, we do this with an iframe to get the post behavior.

My sense is the iframe is the only solution, but I post here in case I've missed something.

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support, or can you limit which browsers to support?

Comment: Recent browsers. At least Chrome and FF. Some IE would be helpful, but I'm interested in the options even if its eliminated from consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript File API (available in Firefox 3.6 or later and latest versions of Chrome and Safari). Basically, you can add an event listener to the `<input>` tag that will fire when a user selects a file. Then, you can upload it using an XMLHttpRequest. Also, the File API can allow you to do other fancy stuff, such as drag-and-drop uploads, getting information about a file before it is sent to the server, and providing a progress bar as a file is uploading.
More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications

This is not a good cross-browser solution because it doesn't have good support in all the popular browsers (*Internet Explorer*), but you could use feature detection in JavaScript to detect if the File API is available and revert back to your iframe method if it is not.